# how to check image is already save in directory

Tags: django

I'm creating a project on mobile's comparison website in Django. I'm using beautifulSoup4 for scraping the mobile's details.
I rendering the scraped data in the Browser as a JSON without storing the data in the database but downloading the image of the mobile.
when a user searches for a phone, it's run the code and grab the data and save the phone's image in the directory.

the problem is that when another user searches for the same phone, program scraped the data and download the image but image filename is already in the directory.

An Error occurs: filename is already in the directory

my Point is - Is there any way to check the image filename is already in the directory or not

here it's my code for saving the image in the directory

```
media_root = 'C:/Users/Goku/PycharmProjects/mysite/media/phone_search_image/'
            local_filename = search+'.jpg'
            link = 'http:'
            link = link + phone_search_image
            r = session.get(link, stream=True, verify=False)
            with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
                for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=720):
                    f.write(chunk)

            current_image_absolute_path = os.path.abspath(local_filename)
            shutil.move(current_image_absolute_path, media_root)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the filename you can just use `isfile`:

```
import os
file_exists = os.path.isfile('filename.png')
```

Comment: its worked..when I gave the full path with the media_root in the  os.path.isfile('media_root'+'image_file_name')  thanks for your idea

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: can you tell me how to access the image in the template using only image_file_name

Comment: If your server can serve static files, you probably just want to pass in the URL. So, if your static files are available at `/static/<file_name>`, then your template will probably need an img tag with that URL.